# Django-rest-framework performance issues

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Hi all this is my view class

```
class ModuleViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = models.Module.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [ModuleViewPermission]
    serializer_class = serializers.ModuleSerializer
```

I have turned the django.db logger to INFO level to see the actual database queries being executed. Following are my findings:

1. Get list of modules:

```
2020-07-26 19:22:18,062 DEBUG utils:110 e70f16f5c7494c8783ca9f5a6bea22c4 (0.013) SELECT "courses_module"."id", "courses_module"."course_id", "courses_module"."name", "courses_module"."number" FROM "courses_module"; args=() django.db.backends
2020-07-26 19:22:18,090 INFO basehttp:154 e70f16f5c7494c8783ca9f5a6bea22c4 "GET /api/courses/modules/ HTTP/1.1" 200 99 django.server
```

2. Get single object:

```
2020-07-26 19:23:26,143 DEBUG utils:110 f1332e4a5e2247709dc784dc2f8b6d19 (0.005) SELECT "courses_module"."id", "courses_module"."course_id", "courses_module"."name", "courses_module"."number" FROM "courses_module"; args=() django.db.backends
2020-07-26 19:23:27,331 DEBUG utils:110 f1332e4a5e2247709dc784dc2f8b6d19 (0.003) SELECT "courses_module"."id", "courses_module"."course_id", "courses_module"."name", "courses_module"."number" FROM "courses_module" WHERE "courses_module"."id" = 1; args=(1,) django.db.backends
2020-07-26 19:23:27,342 DEBUG utils:110 f1332e4a5e2247709dc784dc2f8b6d19 (0.006) SELECT "courses_course"."id", "courses_course"."name", "courses_course"."description", "courses_course"."price_group_id" FROM "courses_course" WHERE "courses_course"."id" = 1; args=(1,) django.db.backends
2020-07-26 19:23:27,359 DEBUG utils:110 f1332e4a5e2247709dc784dc2f8b6d19 (0.015) SELECT "user_user"."id", "user_user"."password", "user_user"."last_login", "user_user"."is_superuser", "user_user"."username", "user_user"."is_staff", "user_user"."is_active", "user_user"."date_joined", "user_user"."email", "user_user"."first_name", "user_user"."last_name" FROM "user_user" INNER JOIN "courses_course_authors" ON ("user_user"."id" = "courses_course_authors"."user_id") WHERE "courses_course_authors"."course_id" = 1; args=(1,) django.db.backends
2020-07-26 19:23:27,375 INFO basehttp:154 f1332e4a5e2247709dc784dc2f8b6d19 "GET /api/courses/modules/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 45 django.server
```

For 1 it may be correct to select all but according to documentation queryset is [cached](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/599e2b183db846a632b1efd148e6bc97d926ee5c/rest_framework/generics.py#L32) for the upcoming requests. But in get_queryset() method we can see that we are [re-evaluating queryset](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/599e2b183db846a632b1efd148e6bc97d926ee5c/rest_framework/generics.py#L72).

Apart from this contradiction. **The results for get single object (pt 2) are more concerning. As we are first selecting all the objects and then again are selecting the module object by Id**. Last 2 queries are for checking user permissions on the object (which are acceptable).

Please let me know if I have something wrong in my views, or if it is a known performance issue of django rest framework. Have also raised this question [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-rest-framework/S-bhj4LHOqA/CU0TmHzJCwAJ)

This can be a major issue in case of millions of records in table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the reason behind this miscellaneous behaviour. Querysets are lazy and they are computed whenever we expect the result. While I was debugging and hovering over the queryset, the queries were being executed as the debugger was expecting the result. I may be wrong. But I was unable to reproduce the above output when I ran it in non debug mode. Following are the logs:
Get List:

```
2020-07-26 23:00:06,697 DEBUG utils:110 1c8a250d8f784aff9c4e5056e446ddf9 (0.004) SELECT "courses_module"."id", "courses_module"."course_id", "courses_module"."name", "courses_module"."number" FROM "courses_module"; args=() django.db.backends
2020-07-26 23:00:06,706 INFO basehttp:154 1c8a250d8f784aff9c4e5056e446ddf9 "GET /api/courses/modules/ HTTP/1.1" 200 99 django.server
```

Get object:

```
2020-07-26 22:59:47,120 DEBUG utils:110 018f23ade3774a44a7cd423c80f6fe59 (0.005) SELECT "courses_module"."id", "courses_module"."course_id", "courses_module"."name", "courses_module"."number" FROM "courses_module" WHERE "courses_module"."id" = 1; args=(1,) django.db.backends
2020-07-26 22:59:47,125 DEBUG utils:110 018f23ade3774a44a7cd423c80f6fe59 (0.004) SELECT "courses_course"."id", "courses_course"."name", "courses_course"."description", "courses_course"."price_group_id" FROM "courses_course" WHERE "courses_course"."id" = 1; args=(1,) django.db.backends
2020-07-26 22:59:47,137 DEBUG utils:110 018f23ade3774a44a7cd423c80f6fe59 (0.011) SELECT "user_user"."id", "user_user"."password", "user_user"."last_login", "user_user"."is_superuser", "user_user"."username", "user_user"."is_staff", "user_user"."is_active", "user_user"."date_joined", "user_user"."email", "user_user"."first_name", "user_user"."last_name" FROM "user_user" INNER JOIN "courses_course_authors" ON ("user_user"."id" = "courses_course_authors"."user_id") WHERE "courses_course_authors"."course_id" = 1; args=(1,) django.db.backends
2020-07-26 22:59:47,168 INFO basehttp:154 018f23ade3774a44a7cd423c80f6fe59 "GET /api/courses/modules/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 45 django.server
```

Still not confirm about caching of queryset for 1(list). Now we are good with 2.

Thanks
Aniket

Comment: cached_queryset = Model.objects.all() #First query --> Slicing it won't result in a query like cached_queryset[0] won't hit the DB ---> But in case of detailed views, it executes a .get() i.e cached_queryset.get(id=1) will hit the database with a query.